# Azure media service function app template deployment failed

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-media-services

I am trying to run live stream video analytics using azure media services.

I have been following the steps defined in the repository-[Github Repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-dotnet-functions-integration/blob/main/media-functions-for-logic-app/LiveStreamAnalysis.md).

I am facing deployment failure of the function app (3rd step of readme).

The detiled error is

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "Conflict",
      "message": "{\r\n  \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
    }
  ]
}
```

The error code *'Conflict'* in azure help documentation says

*You're requesting an operation that isn't allowed in the resource's current state. For example, disk resizing is allowed only when creating a VM or when the VM is deallocated.*

But I am not able to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The sample was developed using AMS v2 and I need to migrate it to AMS v3. There were changes in AMS that could explain the issue you are facing.